# IOS: Storyboard and side menu as facebook app

Tags: objective-c, ios

How do I create a hidden menu with storyboard and Navigation Controller?

Thank you!

Comment: plz give some more info , otherwise too difficult to give ans.

Comment: This is too broad to answer. In short use the UIKit classes to achieve your goal.

Comment: this one also looks nice: https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out this Github project ECSlidingViewController. It is exactly what you're looking for.

https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController

Quoting the projects [read me file](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController):

> ECSlidingViewController is a view controller container for iOS that
>   presents its child view controllers in two layers. It provides
>   functionality for sliding the top view to reveal the views underneath
>   it. This functionality is inspired by the Path 2.0 and Facebook iPhone
>   apps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I can solved my problem with this link!!

Comment: Yes, ECSlidingViewController works brilliantly and is easy to set up. In iOS7 you will likely need to put a plain white view (or whatever colour your background is) behind navigation bar on your top view or there is an annoying bug when selecting the first item in your menu.

Comment: The demo arent compiling for me, did anyone use https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels ? I would like to know if its better